# how to make express routers cleaner when using helper functions

Tags: node.js, express, oop

I'm trying to separate my controllers inside their own files and take advantage of OOP, the question I have is how do I separate helper functions? I'm not talking about utility functions which are going to be used a lot, I mean the functions which you only create to make your code cleaner and are only used one time only.

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const routes = require('./routes');

app.use('/', routes);
```

`routes/index.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const user = require('./user');
router.use('/user', user);
```

`routes/user.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const User = require('./controllers/user');

router.get('/', User.getUser);
router.post('/', User.addUser);
router.put('/', User.updateUser);
```

`controllers/user.js`:

```js
class User {
  static getUser(req, res) {
    // example of getting a user
  }

  static async addUser(req, res) {
    const { username } = req.body;

    if (!username) {
      throw customError(res, 'username is required', 400);
    }

    const exists = await database.find(username);
    if (exists) {
      throw customError(res, 'user with this username already exists.', 409);
    }

    // generate unique id for user
    const id = await genId();

    const user = {
      id,
      username,
    };
    await database.create(user);

    res.status(201).send({
      success: true,
      user,
    });

    // I'm talking about these functions

    function getNum() {
      return Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
    }

    async function isIdUnique(id) {
      const exists = await database.findById(id);
      return !!exists;
    }

    async function genId() {
      const id = getNum();
      const isUnique = await isIdUnique(id);
      if (!isUnique) {
        return genId();
      }
      return id;
    }
  }

  static updateUser(req, res) {
    // example of updating a user
  }
}
```

I think my question is more about the structure but any tips/tricks is appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can separate your utility functions in other directories, i.e. I would name it `/utilities` and put the utility functions in it.

Inside of it, you may categorize your functions into sub-level usages: `lib`, `data`, ...

```
/
|- index.js
|- /contollers
|- /routes
|- /models
|- /utils
|-|- /data
|-|- /lib
|- /node_modules
|- package.json
...
```

I use this kind of configuration often.

So you can put your DB-related functions in `utils/data`, and your other miscellaneous functions in `utils/lib`, ... etc.

Comment: does it make sense to create a function which is going to be used only once inside utilities directory? I'm just trying to think about the next developer who is going to work on the project and make his life easier. is it something usually done and accepted as a good pattern to use?

Comment: @typicallearner even if the function(let's call it **module**) is just used-once-only, I think it is still a good reason to separate it from your main code, because it will make your main code simple, easy to modify the *module*. You don't have to search for the start location of the *module* code in the main code, if it is just simply in separated file.

Comment: And yes, I believe this pattern is used quite broadly, not even in Node.js development.